# Call function which is added dynamically from controller

Tags: angularjs

```
for (var i = 'A', k = 1; i <= 'Z', k <= $scope.noOfColumns; i = $scope.nextChar(i), k++)
{
    for (var j = 1; j <= $scope.noOfSeatsperRow; j++)
    {
        seats += '<div id=' + i + '' + j + ' class="seat" ng-click="selectOrDeselect($event)">'+ i + '' + j + '</div>';
        if (j == $scope.noOfSeatsperRow)
        {
            seats += '<br />';
        }
        if (j == $scope.noOfSeatsperRow/2)
        {
            seats += '<div class="gap"></div>';
        }
    }
}
angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("seats")).html(seats);
```

Here I am appending some HTML to pre-existing element. The problem is whenever I click `ng-click` event should invoke but it is not happening

I tried by giving statically in the view using for loop of razor there I can get the `ng-click` event invoked

What was the problem and how can I overcome with this?

Comment: ...What is this?  Why aren't you using a standard `ngRepeat` for this sort of thing?

Comment: Good lord, thats some interesting stuff there...

Comment: This is not displaying data this is to add some div tags to the existing html @Makoto

Comment: ...but you're doing this in a controller, and not in the DOM (where you can invoke repeats on a collection) or in a directive (where DOM manipulation actually makes *sense* to do).

Comment: Then it is a wrong approach? How can I make this correct.... Could you please help @Makoto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i = 'A', k = 1; i <= 'Z', k <= $scope.noOfColumns; i = $scope.nextChar(i), k++)
{
    for (var j = 1; j <= $scope.noOfSeatsperRow; j++)
    {
        seats += '<div id=' + i + '' + j + ' class="seat" ng-click="selectOrDeselect($event)">' + i + '' + j + '</div>';
        if (j == $scope.noOfSeatsperRow)
        {
            seats += '<br />';
        }
        if (j == $scope.noOfSeatsperRow/2)
        {
            seats += '<div class="gap"></div>';
        }
    }
}

angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("seats")).append($compile(seats)($scope));
```

I got the solution using "append($compile(seats)($scope));" made that.